# Keeping elements (from list of vectors) that do not have a proper subset within that list (in R)

Tags: r, list, vector, set

Proper subset: A proper subset S' of a set S is a subset that is strictly contained in S and so excludes S itself (note I am also excluding the empty set).

Suppose you have the following vectors in a list:

```
a = c(1,2)
b = c(1,3)
c = c(2,4)
d = c(1,2,3,4)
e = c(2,4,5)
f = c(1,2,3)
```

My aim is to keep only vectors which have no proper subset within the list, which in this example would be a, b and c. The following code is my solution,

```
possibilities = list(a,b,c,d,e,f)

final.list <- possibilities

for (i in possibilities) {
  for (j in rev(possibilities)) {
    if (all(i %in% j) & !all(j %in% i)) {
      final.list <- final.list[!(final.list %in% list(j))]
    } else {
      final.list <- final.list
    }
  }
}
```

which gives the intended output, though I am concerned with the scalability of this approach. Does anyone have an idea for a more efficient approach? Thanks!

* Note that for my true purpose the length of the possibilities list--and its sub-vectors--can grow quite large.

Comment: How do you define the proper subset?

Comment: Thanks, definition added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `purrr` option could be:

```
map2(.x = possibilities,
     .y = seq_along(possibilities),
     ~ !any(map_lgl(possibilities[-.y], function(z) all(z %in% .x))))

[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE

[[6]]
[1] FALSE
```

To keep only the target vectors:

```
keep(possibilities,
     map2_lgl(.x = possibilities,
              .y = seq_along(possibilities),
              ~ !any(map_lgl(possibilities[-.y], function(z) all(z %in% .x)))))

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you. My intended output is a list including only the target vectors. How would I get that from the logical vector returned here?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding can you please show a situation when there could be diverging results?

Comment: I think you will see a diverging result if you try over `possibilities = list(a,a)`. If you applied `function(z) all(z %in% .x) & length(z) < length(.x)`, the results converges.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I'm not sure how to treat two identical sets. It may require some further clarification from the OP.

Comment: OP's code `all(i %in% j) & !all(j %in% i)` filters out the cases that have identical sets. Mathematically, if set `A` is a proper subset of set `B`, then `A`'s cardinality should be strictly less than `B`. That's the reason I compared the lengths of two sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
final.list <- subset(
  possibilities,
  sapply(
    seq_along(possibilities),
    function(k) {
      !any(sapply(
        possibilities[-k],
        function(v) all(v %in% possibilities[[k]]) & length(v) < length(possibilities[[k]])
      ))
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
> final.list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 4
```