# Keeping vectors (from list of vectors) whose elements do not have a proper subset within that same list (using RCPP)

Tags: r, rcpp

I have asked this question previously [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452018/keeping-elements-from-list-of-vectors-that-do-not-have-a-proper-subset-within) and received a satisfactory answer using the `purr` package. However, this has proved to be a bottle neck in my program so I would like to rewrite the section using the `RCPP` package.

**Proper subset**: A proper subset S' of a set S is a subset that is strictly contained in S and so excludes S itself (note I am also excluding the empty set).

Suppose you have the following vectors in a list:

```
a = c(1,2)
b = c(1,3)
c = c(2,4)
d = c(1,2,3,4)
e = c(2,4,5)
f = c(1,2,3)
```

My aim is to keep only vectors which have no proper subset within the list, which in this example would be a, b and c.

**Previous Solution**

```
library(purr)

possibilities <- list(a,b,c,d,e,f)
keep(possibilities,
     map2_lgl(.x = possibilities,
              .y = seq_along(possibilities),
              ~ !any(map_lgl(possibilities[-.y], function(z) all(z %in% .x)))))
```

Comment: FYI: It is spelled Rcpp. Capital R, lowercase cpp.

Comment: And your question (which I didn't downvote) will likely get closed. This isn't 'write me code' ordering service. There is zero Rcpp in your question, besides wishing "wouldn't it be nice if this existing code ran faster".

Comment: Not my downvote either, but it might be worth exploring other base R optimisations as well. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions @MauritsEvers thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion here is to avoid the O(N^3) and use a less order instead. The other answer provided here will be slow still since it is greater than O(N^2). Here is a solution with less than O(N^2), where the worst case scenario is O(N^2) when all the elements are unique.

```
onlySet <- function(x){
   i <- 1
  repeat{
    y <- sapply(x[-1], function(el)!all(is.element(x[[1]], el)))
    if(all(y)){
      if(i==length(x)) break
      else i <- i+1
    }
    x <- c(x[-1][y], x[1])
  }
  x
}
```

Now to show the time difference, check out the following:

```
match_fun <- Vectorize(function(s1, s2) all(s1 %in% s2))
method1 <- function(a){
 mat <- outer(a, a, match_fun)
 a[colSums(mat) == 1]
}

poss <- rep(possibilities, 100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(method1(poss), onlySet(poss))

Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 method1(poss) 840.7919 880.12635 932.255030 889.36380 923.32555 1420.1077   100   b
 onlySet(poss)   1.9845   2.07005   2.191647   2.15945   2.24245    3.3656   100  a
```

Comment: Very nice. (+1). Do you mind adding OPs original method in the `microbenchmark` as well? I'm curious how that compares...

Comment: @MauritsEvers dont even try that since it is more than O(N^3). The OP code alone without takes almost 3 seconds. So definitely take forever for a list of length 600

Comment: I see. I've added another (recursive) option that is on par with your performant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried optimising the solution in base R first? For example, the following reproduces your expected output and uses (faster) base R array routines:

```r
match_fun <- Vectorize(function(s1, s2) all(s1 %in% s2))
mat <- outer(possibilities, possibilities, match_fun)
possibilities[colSums(mat) == 1]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 4
```

---

Inspired by Onyambu's performant solution, here is another base R option using a recursive function

```r
f_recursive <- function(x, i = 1) {
    if (i > length(x)) return(x)
    idx <- which(sapply(x[-i], function(el) all(x[[i]] %in% el))) + 1
    if (length(idx) == 0) f_recursive(x, i + 1) else f_recursive(x[-idx], i + 1)
}
f(possibilities)
```

The performance is on par with Onyambu's solution.

```r
poss <- rep(possibilities, 100)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    method1(poss),
    onlySet(poss),
    f_recursive(poss))
#Unit: milliseconds
#              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
#     method1(poss) 682.558602 710.974831 750.325377 730.627996 765.040976
#     onlySet(poss)   1.700646   1.782713   1.870972   1.819820   1.918669
# f_recursive(poss)   1.681120   1.737459   1.884685   1.806384   1.901582
#         max neval
# 1200.562889   100
#    2.371646   100
#    3.217013   100
```